# "if (pid = fork() > 0)" - Why is fork() returning pid 1 (systemd)?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork

In my main() function I have a call to fork() in a loop that is successfully creating three child processes.

code is similar to this:

```
    int pid = -1;
    int num_processes = 3;
    int pid_array[num_processes];
    for (i = 0; i < num_processes; i++)
    {
        if (pid = fork() > 0)
        {
            pid_array[i] = pid;
            //do parent stuff
        }
    }
```

I can see with 'ps -ef' that the child processes are getting created and have the correct pid for the parent process listed, also these processes are running and functioning properly.

The problem is that I need to store the child pids in the parent's pid_array, but they are all being stored as 1. In gdb I see the fork() is returning a 1 each time instead of the child pid as I would expect.

So it's returning a 1 which is the pid for systemd. Why is it returning pid 1 (systemd) rather than the pids of the child processes which were sucessfully created?

For good measure, the man page for fork on my system:

```
   RETURN VALUE
           On success, the PID of the child process is returned  in  the  parent,  and  0  is
           returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process
           is created, and errno is set appropriately.
```

Comment: precedence: `(pid = fork() > 0)` -->> `((pid = fork()) > 0)`

Comment: Incidentally, this kind of mistake is part of why Python chooses not to have assignments return a value -- forcing the assignment and the comparison into two separate lines prevents the misunderstanding at hand.

Comment: side note: you're creating more than 3 process overall this way, each child is also forking off too.

Comment: in the full code I had it break out of the loop on (pid == 0)

Comment: And some people wonder why doing assignments in conditional clauses is a bad idea...

Answer (score 3):

```
pid = fork() > 0
```

fork return value is greater than 0, hence, fork() return value is indeed greater than 0, unless fork sys_call fail, pid gets assign 1.

Answer (score 3):

`>` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=`.

Therefore `pid = fork() > 0` is equivalent to `pid = (fork() > 0)`. This tests whether the result of `fork()` is greater than zero, and assigns the result of the test to `pid`. Thus `pid` will always be zero or one.

What you want is `(pid = fork()) > 0`.

Comment: ...or `pid = fork(); if (pid > 0)`, to make it clear enough that a reader doesn't even need to think about precedence.